# how to insert buttons in datatable row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datatable

I have now the code to get the list of objects that I will use to fill datatable, but I want to add a buton in each row. How to do that ?

```
var hCols = [];
model = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.TableData));
var columns = [];
data = JSON.parse(model);
columnNames = Object.keys(data[0]);
for (var i in columnNames) {
    columns.push({
        data: columnNames[i],
        title: columnNames[i]//capitalizeFirstLetter(columnNames[i])
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that from your code, the data is passed via viewbag which comes from the server. I think the correct way of doing this is, instead of rendering the data from your script, you render the data from the server (Razor syntax) then initialize the datatable.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Property</th>
          <th>Button</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <!--Server Side Rendering-->
        @foreach(var i in ViewBag.TableData){
          <tr>
            <td>@i.PropertyName</td>
            <td>
              <button href="#">@i.PropertyName</button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        }
      </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
      // Include jquery and datatable library
      // Initialize datatable

      $(document).ready(function(){
        var table = $('.table').DataTable();
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```